# Replace a particular text in every line from a text file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd

I have a text file I want to remove all the ending 0s in every line upto line no 19 using batch script

I have written a code for finding specific line. And no idea how to move forward

I want the text file modified without ending 0s in each line

novamth.txt file

```
ATC4            C   5   0
CTY         C   3   0
CTY_DESCR           C   21  0
E_DT_PRTEXP         C   43  0
E_YR_PRTEXP         C   41  0
GEN_PRD         C   28  0
LNCH_STATUS         C   22  0
MNF         C   18  0
NAME_TYPE           C   22  0
NFC123          C   3   0
PRD         C   18  0
PRE_PST_EXP         C   28  0
PROT_ECTION         C   24  0
REL_PROT_EXP_MTH            C   40  0
REL_PROT_EXP_YR         C   31  0
STR         C   6   0
INTSTR          C   52  0
PCK         C   31  0
INTPCK          C   72  0
    KG  MTH_04_2017 N   35  15
    KG  MTH_05_2017 N   35  15
    KG  MTH_06_2017 N   35  15
    KG  MTH_07_2017 N   35  15
    KG  MTH_08_2017 N   35  15
```

bat file to find a particular line

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LineNumber=19
set FileName=C:\PADDS\bat\nova\novamth.txt
set counter=0

for /F "delims=" %%j in ('type "%FileName%"') do (
  set /A counter+=1
  if !counter! equ %LineNumber% (echo.%%j> "myline.txt" & goto :END)
)
:END
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read these help articles: [ask] and [mcve]!

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044): `call jrepl "0$" "" /inc "1:19" /f "file.txt" /o -`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you have a few options, but, let's just address the basics you have already laid out as you almost have a working version!

I am going to wrap your sets in " so we don't end up with any errant characters in them.

```
 @(
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo off
 )
 set "LineNumber=19"
 set "FileName=C:\PADDS\bat\nova\novamth.txt"
 set "counter=1"

 For /F "tokens=*" %%j in ('type "%FileName%"') do (
    Set /A "counter+=1"
    Set "_Line=%%j"
    IF /I !counter! leq %LineNumber% (
       Set "_Line=!_Line:~0,-1!"
    )
    echo(!_Line!>> "myline.txt" 
 )

 :END
 (
    EndLocal
    Exit /B
  )
```

I am storing the line in a temp variable `_Line` and removing THE LAST CHARACTER from that string, as it appears you do not have any trailing spaces this is the simplest method.
This change happens only on the first 19 lines, after that we just write it as-is.

`>>` is used to append to the file, as `>` would over-write each time a line was written.

In the above version which will work for the data provided this will remove ALL 0s.  This can be changed if 0 can occur in locations other than the last bit of the line.  I was writing this on mobile in the shower and thought I had edited to include that info but it was not there so now this should help :)

In any case, if you DO have data that CAN have 0s, can we at least assume there will always be 4 terms?

Also, are there ever trailing spaces it looks like no, so I will assume that?

Do you need to preserve all the spaces? (I'll assume Yes)  Even the ones which come before that last 0? (I'll assume Yes for now but it would be easy to remove them as you will see)

I'll assume that the answers as above in writing the next iteration.

**I have amended this further to provide explicit output of the file created for the author to review as the Author was not able to find it.**

I also changed the variables slightly when adding he path variable for the author to edit.

Also I decided to add it he delete of the Output File in case it already exists, although not specifically asked for, in case the author already had run this before.

```
REM Script: %~f0
REM Version: 1.0.0
@(
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo off
)
SET "_LineNumber=19"
SET "_SourceFileName=C:\PADDS\bat\nova\novamth.txt"
SET "_OutputFileName=C:\PADDS\bat\nova\myline.txt"
SET "_Counter=1"

DEL /F /Q "%_OutputFileName%"

For /F "tokens=*" %%j in ('type "%_SourceFileName%"') do (
    SET /A "_Counter+=1"
    SET "_Line=%%j"
    IF /I !_Counter! leq %_LineNumber% (
        FOR /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_012345678910" %%J IN ("%%j") DO @(
            SET "_Space_1=%%J"
            SET "_Space_2=%%K"
            SET "_Space_3=%%L"
        )
        FOR /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims= " %%J IN ("%%j") DO @(
            SET "_Line=%%J!_Space_1!%%K!_Space_2!%%L!_Space_3!"
        )
    )
    echo(!_Line!>>"%_OutputFileName%"
)

(
    ECHO. Check the File "%_OutputFileName%"
    EndLocal
    Exit /B
)
```

In the above, I now am taking the whole line initially, and if the count is less than or equal to 19, we can easily use a second loop to get set of spaces by using all of the non-space characters we may expect instead as the delimiters instead of space.

This allows us to capture all of the spaces found between each term into some variables.

The For Loop following this grabs the Terms themselves and re-uses the for loop variables since they are destroyed once out of the previous loop.

Here we do not need to assign any variables other than the _Line variable because we have collected all of the information we need. so we use the terms which hold the data and separate them with the Spaces variables found in the previous step.

Once we have constructed the new LINE variable we're done with our If statement, and now there is no need to have separate ECHO statements (in all honesty even in the first there wasn't but I was writing it quickly on mobile and it seemed easier not to make it shorter.

(I've amended the original to not have separate echos, as well, I always prefer that where possible as I feel it's cleaner.)

I've amended this to have a specific output path for your file in a variable you can edit, and to provide that path on the CMD Line.

**Example of Running the CMD script it at CLI:**

```
Y:\>C:\PADDS\bat\nova\testnovamth.cmd

Y:\>REM Script: C:\PADDS\bat\nova\testnovamth.cmd

Y:\>REM Version: 1.0.0
 Check the File "C:\PADDS\bat\nova\myline.txt"

Y:\>
```

**Example output from the script:**

```
ATC4            C   5   
CTY         C   3   
CTY_DESCR           C   21  
E_DT_PRTEXP         C   43  
E_YR_PRTEXP         C   41  
GEN_PRD         C   28  
LNCH_STATUS         C   22  
MNF         C   18  
NAME_TYPE           C   22  
NFC123          C   3   
PRD         C   18  
PRE_PST_EXP         C   28  
PROT_ECTION         C   24  
REL_PROT_EXP_MTH            C   40  
REL_PROT_EXP_YR         C   31  
STR         C   6   
INTSTR          C   52  
PCK         C   31  
INTPCK          C   72  0
KG  MTH_04_2017 N   35  15
KG  MTH_05_2017 N   35  15
KG  MTH_06_2017 N   35  15
KG  MTH_07_2017 N   35  15
KG  MTH_08_2017 N   35  15
```

Comment: sorry, but `!_Line:0=!` removes *every* zero, not just the one at the very end.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this on Mobile and had meant to include that info in the posting along with a note that I would make a better version once I was off mobile unless there would be no such cases as this will work for the provided info.  However, I guess sit didn't post I was rushing typing that while I had to get out of the shower to get the kids ready for daycare though so I guess it didn't post, the last edit.  It's a little hard writing on mobile I find.  Thanks for the heads up @Stephan! :)

Comment: Your second approach looks much better - and even keeps the whitespaces between (be it spaces or tabs or a mixture). I added some quotes around `%%j` in both `for ... in ("%%j")... ` to process them as strings, not filenames and so making your script actually work.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that it was a small mistake on my end, simple mistakes happen due to ot human error when you can't test.  Not sure what you mean by "Looks Better" both are valid approaches, the second one is over-kill if he never has 0s in the other text.it's something I have had to learn that often the second answer is over-kill, Stack admins often do not like it when you do anything more than the bare minimum necessary in my experience.

Comment: well, there *is* `REL_PROT_EXP_MTH     C   40  0` in the data example, so definitely the first approach makes unwanted changes (`40`->`4`)

Comment: Ahh, I had not seen it or I woudl have been more understanding and not bothered with that approach in the 1st place.  I did not know if there were trailing whitespace on the phone either, but on seeing it on the desktop now I know there is not or I would have used `!_Line:~0,-1!`  Seeing as how there are not and there was a 0 in the first 19 lines I missed I'll amend it to that anyway then as it shoudln;t leave the one that does not fit the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But this doesn't remove the 0s. Or actually does anything.

Comment: `C:\PADDS\bat\nova>(
Set /A "counter+=1"
 Set "_Line=ATC4                        C       5       0"
 IF /I !counter! LEQ 19 (
FOR /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_012345678910" %J IN ("ATC4
                C       5       0") DO @(
SET "_Space_1=%J"
 SET "_Space_2=%K"
 SET "_Space_3=%L"
 PAUSE
)
 FOR /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims= " %J IN ("ATC4                      C       5
0") DO @(
SET "_Line=%J!_Space_1!%K!_Space_2!%L!_Space_3!"
 PAUSE
)
)
 echo(!_Line! 1>>"myline.txt"
)
`

Comment: This is the command line output with echo on. Is there any way I can share screenshot here?

Comment: @webdesign247  Works for me, although I prefer to explicitly place the path for myfile so I know where it will be for sure, I assumed you would know where i was and/or wanted it where the cmd script was going to run.  I've amended it to have it hard coded and I added the output from my test run I just did.